# Swift populating tableview with json from url using Alamofire

Tags: json, url, swift, tableview, alamofire

This sort of works but the issue is I believe the table is being generated before alamofire has a chance to grab the json file. If I print out self.dates after loading it displays fine. Is there a way to pause the view while it loads. Or am I taking a completely wrong approach here? Thanks

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var dates: [String] = []
var times: [String] = []

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    loadPosts()
}

func loadPosts() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:5000/listposts")
        .responseSwiftyJSON {(request, response, jsonObj, error) in
            for index in 0...jsonObj.count-1 {
                self.dates.append(jsonObj[index]["appDate"].stringValue)
                self.times.append(jsonObj[index]["appTime"].stringValue)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView!.reloadData()
            })
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonPress() {
    self.tableView!.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dates.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.dates[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.times[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
}
```

Comment: I did not understand the problem, are you getting empty table in display ?

Comment: Ya no cells are being placed/filled. If I print self.dates.count in tableview it returns 0. If I use the button to print it it shows the right count

Comment: Code is look fine do one thing just called tableView.reloadData in loadPosts, and remove from other places and do write println line which will log that when reload table is called when Alamofire get json data and put that log in ur question

Comment: Looks fine to me. You mentioned that you do get data back but I would wrap your response handler in an error checker just incase.

Comment: Did you create an IB file automatically or are you creating the table VC in code? In any case check if you've correctly set your tableView delegate and dataSource to be set to "self". This could explain why your table view overriden functions are not called.